# JavaScript / AppleScript: Get current time of html video

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, applescript

I’d like to get the current time of [this](http://southpark.cc.com/full-episodes/s18e06) video (user agent must be set to iOS 10, iPhone) using Applescript or Javascript within AppleScript.

As it is possible to change the video position with this…

```
tell application "Safari"

do JavaScript "document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].currentTime = " & 90

end tell
```

… I thought something like this…

```
tell application "Safari"

    set ttime to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].currentTime()"

    return ttime

end tell
```

… would do the trick - but it doesn’t. Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTMLMediaElement.currentTime` is a property, not a function. You don't need to call it, so remove the parentheses:

```
set ttime to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].currentTime"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final result:

```
tell application „Safari"

set ttime to do JavaScript „document.getElementsByTagName(‘video')[0].currentTime;" in document 1

return ttime

end tell
```

I’ d like to give both of you credit but I can’t :(
Thank you!